# Generic Definition Causing "Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'Parameters<Method>'"

Tags: typescript

I have been looking at trying to take a fairly open definition from a 3rd party library and give a more narrow definition for our needs. For some reason I see this error where I think it should work?

```
Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'Parameters<IIpcInvokeMethods[K]>'?
```

Given this typescript:

[Error Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFEA0BVwJQHIEEAyoUEkBCclwJqgAi4AYhghtBgPIIBcAUACYCmAxgDYCGATq6AB23ALasAzgAdu7AeE4cALrwD2g0AG9GoHaACWgxa14AzGQIyT2AWW4GMggG4qA1q3CPWh0KwAeRwWZxCE9vLV0I0BBiFXZxelAAC0VFSXiQVgV2ZTUAK3EAOhVeAHNgZljxYG5JPWBxZQBXbMb%20Kr0rAFoRO0FOg2c3TtZQxW1InWiiVhMDPUU9NVA4VhEVT2ZQUmKIX1FJBXGdAF9GI-1DYzNZUEsbXp9-LyDQBBU2ACkAZQKPL0VwCJ5kZeJpzhFEtxAgoABTsSGCQSZBINXgGEoAGlAnD0DS8xgSMJG-wSd1s9icrncoyxBTpfBK8VAUIAngBtAC6AEpQABeAB8oBhAAVVEDxKwADzOPTMfk8gA%20QtZXK5CRlzAA3OdTqczuw1A19FZyYJSSaHrzNMdmcFWdrFCzJBYLQY%20RAsjlBAUyb1tYxogBhACqX2gNGs6BoAHEMIHQOHXng4DQAOrEMgUKi0BCgGikY33AxnR3O253ByDVjWViKRLvYJW8K6ADkHRstfrzCQLcJPIFoFFKnFUo1-Ix5zbJs77ywvaFBiI3EU3BRynR-cFQ5HkoARioVAoofzGMd-aWLBXKW4a3X3tAnRJ3eB-LwZIpJW4WSoTOWrJWqVvLtxCxVF0X5c9Hz-dgAJvGdmGFPhRHESVoEeAIXgwK8qyA%209H3EQUrUQt8xBBFCsP-a9q3g8Q2WgDkIMYC9oNg6i72YFZFFaQRUPQ55ggomCqNw5gH2dAj3U47ixKlQTWJE2j6MYpioMEgAJKFmAUd1mx0BEtKlABpPjAgE7DAPgmSCLhBEkU4BJDKxHE8SRXhCWJQwEnkJRVG9X0KSrP5DFpelSiZOThPg4jkMlQz5T5QUIpw%20CpN4Hi4rVUANW1PUQBk0AW1ZTkW30YJBBURRbXEPQSmEXdtMUFRQGYltotI4xyPMuD2NowyGJbAB%20RgDUEI121NYNJGYZdWFJO4NOhAQrXGv0zhWgxJumowCn02Epw7di5yxGEDCCxQsUXZduE3MEIn4Li0sHMVcVYAo2kPTwYSaVguRy37GCAA)

Is there a way to make that generic definition work and maintain the typing?

```
// EXTERNAL LIBRARY DEFINITION:
declare namespace Electron {
    interface IpcMainInvokeEvent extends Event {
        // Docs: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/structures/ipc-main-invoke-event
        // Definition Removed For Example
    }

    interface IpcMain extends NodeJS.EventEmitter {
        handle(channel: string, listener: (event: IpcMainInvokeEvent, ...args: any[]) => (Promise<void>) | (any)): void;
    }
}


const ipcMain: IpcMain = {} as any;
type IpcMain = Electron.IpcMain;

// CUSTOM LOGIC TO NARROW DEFINITION OF ipcMain

type IIpcInvokeMethods = {
    'ipcMethodA': () => Promise<void>,
    'ipcMethodB': (inData: string) => Promise<boolean>
};

type IIpcInvokeMethodTypes = Extract<keyof IIpcInvokeMethods, string>;

type IIpcInvokeMethodParams<T extends IIpcInvokeMethodTypes> = Parameters<IIpcInvokeMethods[T]>;
type IIpcInvokeMethodReturn<T extends IIpcInvokeMethodTypes> = ReturnType<IIpcInvokeMethods[T]>;

type IIpcHandle = {
    handle<K extends IIpcInvokeMethodTypes>(channel: K, listener: (event: Electron.IpcMainInvokeEvent, ...args: IIpcInvokeMethodParams<K>) => IIpcInvokeMethodReturn<K>): void;
}

//Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'Parameters<IIpcInvokeMethods[K]>'?
const ipcMainUpdate: IIpcHandle = ipcMain;

ipcMainUpdate.handle('ipcMethodB', (inEvent, inData) => {
    return Promise.resolve(true);
});
```